# Constructing arcs using \pgfpatharctoprecomputed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am having trouble producing an arc from a well-defined ellipse using \pgfpatharctoprecomputed. My code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=\jobname.svg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-25,-25) grid (25,25);  
\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}

\node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{Chloromethane.png}};

\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-10.0cm}{-2.0cm}}
{\pgfpoint{-3.5cm}{10.5cm}}
{\pgfpoint{-6.5cm}{2.0cm}}
\pgfusepath{draw}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-16.2cm}{-0.8cm}}
\pgfpatharcto{6.8007cm}{11.068cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{-16.7cm}{7.6cm}}
\pgfusepath{draw}

%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2.75cm}{-10.0cm}}
%\pgfpatharcto{6.8007cm}{11.068cm}{17.1}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{-12.1cm}{7.9cm}}
%\pgfusepath{draw}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2.75cm}{-10.0cm}}
\pgfpatharctoprecomputed{\pgfpoint{-10.0cm}{-2.0cm}}{-47.8156}{101.976} {\pgfpoint{-12.1cm}{7.9cm}}{6.801cm}{11.068cm}{0.61447}{1.6274}
\pgfusepath{draw}

%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{11cm}{0.5cm}}
%\pgfpatharcto{11cm}{9cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{-3.5cm}{-7.5cm}}
%\pgfusepath{draw} 

\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-2.5cm}{1.5cm}}
{\pgfpoint{17.5cm}{9.5cm}}
{\pgfpoint{-8.0cm}{11.0cm}}
\pgfusepath{draw}

%\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.0cm}{1cm}}
%{\pgfpoint{-10.7cm}{1.5cm}}
%{\pgfpoint{0.75cm}{7.1cm}}
%\pgfusepath{draw}

\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-2.5cm}{1.5cm}}
{\pgfpoint{17.4cm}{9.4cm}}
{\pgfpoint{0.0cm}{4.0cm}}
\pgfusepath{draw}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the arc does not form correctly upon using the above code:

[image]

and, in particular, \pgfpatharctoprecomputed. Is there any alternative code I could use to reproduce an arc from a well-defined ellipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to achieve the desired output using the alternative command "\pgfpatharcto". In order to produce the arc, I had to define the angle with which the ellipse is tilted with respect to the vertical.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=\jobname.svg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-25,-25) grid (25,25);
\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}

%\node (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{Chloromethane.png}};

%\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-10.0cm}{-2.0cm}}
%{\pgfpoint{-5.7cm}{10.5cm}}
%{\pgfpoint{-4.5cm}{-2.5cm}}
%\pgfusepath{draw}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-16.2cm}{-0.8cm}}  
\pgfpatharcto{5.148cm}{11.947cm}{28.496}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{-16.7cm}{7.6cm}}
\pgfusepath{draw}

%\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-2.75cm}{-10.0cm}}
%\pgfpatharctoprecomputed{\pgfpoint{-10.0cm}{-2.0cm}}{-47.8156}{101.976} {\pgfpoint{-12.1cm}{7.9cm}}{5.148cm}{11.947cm}{0.4309}{2.3207}
%\pgfusepath{draw}

\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-12.1cm}{7.9cm}}
\pgfpatharcto{5.148cm}{11.947cm}{28.496}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{-2.75cm}{-10.0cm}}
\pgfusepath{draw}

\draw [fill] (-15.7,8.5) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (-14.5,-4.5) circle [radius=0.1];

\draw [fill] (-12.1,7.9) circle [radius=0.1];
\draw [fill] (-2.75,-10.0) circle [radius=0.1];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Some of the necessary points to define the arc are also marked in the attached PNG file. A second arc from the same ellipse in the original question is also displayed. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The initial point is not on the defined ellipse that's why the start and the end points are wiggling. Eyeballing a bit better gives decent result but I think your y radius is also problematic.

Note that, this command is especially useful if you are doing the computations beforehand. For eyeballing, this is not very useful. See the red ellipse I've drawn.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-25,-25) grid (25,25);  
\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}

\draw[red,line width=3mm] (-10,-3) ellipse (6.801 and 11.068);
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-4.75cm}{-10.0cm}}
\pgfpatharctoprecomputed{\pgfpoint{-10.0cm}{-3.0cm}}{-47.8156}{101.976} {\pgfpoint{-12.1cm}{7.55cm}}{6.801cm}{11.068cm}{0.61447}{1.6274}
\pgfusepath{draw}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: @stars83clouds look at your own grid. I basically counted from the grid. They cannot be on the ellipse as I basically show in my example.

Comment: apologies, the code for the ellipse I am referring to is there but it is not indicated in the figure - you can see it now in my updated figure from my original post. As you can see, the two points are indeed on the "black" ellipse.

Comment: You are correct @percusse, the radii were incorrect. However, I am unable to reproduce the desired output like in my answer below using "\pgfpatharctoprecomputed".